# How to add image in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: image, matlab

I want to switch back and forth between two images, like blinking: 1 second for the first image and one second for second image.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not totally sure of what you want to do (specifically what type of images you are trying to display), but here's some sample code that may do what you want:

```
image1 = imread('cameraman.tif');  % Load a test image
image2 = imread('circles.png');    % Load another test image

hAxes = gca;  % Get a handle to the current axes

for iLoop = 1:5,  % Loop five times
  imshow(image1,'Parent',hAxes);
  pause(1);
  imshow(image2,'Parent',hAxes);
  pause(1);
end
```

I used the general function [IMSHOW](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/images/imshow.html), but this sometimes changes other properties of the figure/axes and that may not be to your liking (since you mention adding this to an existing GUI). You may want to use the [IMAGE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/image.html) function instead. Also, instead of the for loop you could use a while loop that stops switching images when a condition is met (such as a button press).

Answer (score 2):

How are your images stored in Matlab? As a matlab movie or a 3 or 4 dimensional matrix depending on if the images are color or grayscale. Also, if you have the image processing toolbox, `implay` and `immovie`. Another option assuming that your images are in a `mxnx3xk` (rgb color) or a `mxnxk` (gray scale) matrix. Then the following should work. Assuming the following

- `Img` - matrix storing image data either with dimensions `mxnx3xk`
  or `mxnxk`
- `handles.imageAxes` -
  handle for the axis you want to
  display the image (set the tag of the
  axis to imageAxes in GUIDE)

Now you can loop through Img

```
for i=1:k
    % display the i^th image use `Img(:,:,i)` for a gray scale stack
    image(Img(:,:,:,i),'parent',handles.imageAxes);
    pause(1) % pause one second
end
```

that's it.